# How to add Overflowing div automatically to adjacent Div in Angular 2?

Tags: css, angular, angular-directive

I am working on a document editor application using Angular 6. It has a paper element which looks like a paper of fixed size.

The user can add multiple child elements(Angular components) to this paper element.

When the user adds children that occupy more space than the parent could afford, the div needs to be added automatically to the next div and if any of the child Divs are deleted, then the overflowing div needs to be added back to the 1st paper.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I have made a simplified stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b31g71).

Comment: For position problem, have you look https://github.com/angular/flex-layout ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe. You can show only max count of child elements on page. But i think you must calculate count of pages and display it by ngFor. Good luck!